# How to load bashrc in all open tabs

Tags: bash

Sometimes I change my prompt on .bashrc and I want to source the file so I can get the new version. But usually I've many open tabs simultaneously. Is there any way/command to source the .bashrc file in all open tabs?

I saw that [Terminator](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.pt/p/introduction.html) allows to send the command to multiple tabs, but I do not use it...

Comment: This is not really about bash but rather your windowing terminal program. As an example, if you are using Terminal on OS X (?) you might use OS X Automator.

Comment: This question is more a general computing question than it is programming-related so it’s off-topic for StackOverflow.
You’d have a better chance of getting useful answers at [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer available at [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/570000/source-new-bashrc-in-all-open-terminals)

thanks to [Anthony Geoghegan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1640661/anthony-geoghegan)